# Convert compass to css programmatically

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I have a string of compass style in my ruby code. I want to convert it into a css string. I have values of config.rb as a hash.

How do I convert the compass in string format to css (string) via function call?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it:

```
require 'sass'

scss_string = '@mixin test{width: auto}; div {@include test}'

print Sass::compile(scss_string)
```

This will output:

```
div {
  width: auto; }
```

[Here you have the link to the ruby doc for this method, with information about how to customize it](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/s/sass-3.1.19/Sass.html#method-c-compile).

Comment: So what if your sass string is dependent on compass itself i.e. `darken($color, 10%)`? Using `Sass.compile` will result in an import error because it has no idea about compass.